# ext js 3.4 RegExp filtering

Tags: regex, extjs, filter, compare, field

How can I make something like this in my filtering in grid

```
var filters = [
   {
       fn: function (item) {

           return (item.get('Name') == new RegExp(".*" + productValue + ".*"))
                  && item.get('IsActive') == activeValue;
       }
   }
];
```

this part is what i want to get but its not working

```
(item.get('Name') == new RegExp(".*" + productValue + ".*"))
```

Comment: try to add a question mark after the first asterisk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way RegExp work. That should be:

```
(new RegExp(productValue)).test(item.get('Name'))
```

See the doc for [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), and its [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

Note the regex will match anywhere if you don't add `^` (beginning) or `$` (end) markers, so you don't have to add '.*'.

Now, for this simple test, you'd only need to do:

```
item.get('Name').indexOf(productValue) !== -1
```